# Is there a way to see what bonus objectives I missed?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm certain I missed one bonus objective early on, and as such Kerrigan is down one level from where she could be.  Is there an easy way to see what level I missed it on so I can replay it from the archives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The archives themselves hold the answer:

[image]

Just parse the list of levels, and eventually you'll find the mission you're missing the bonus objectives from.

Comment: I thought it would be obvious, but wow, if it was a baneling, it would have blown up in my face.